# One way SSL Server Socket in Java - Client can be SSL or non-SSL

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I want to create a server which communicate via SSLServerSocket(one way SSL) So that client can validate the server(server didn't need to validate the client).

But I don't want to enforce one way SSL. Means if client want to send a request from a normal Socket(instead of SSLSocket which have my public cert in his trust store), it should still allow the connection.
Means client can Connect via either Socket or SSLSocket both way should work.

I have tried to implement that, so I have created one SSLServerSocket in which i have added my KeyStore(which contain Server's private key). With SSLSocket(client) it is working. But when I was trying to connect with Socket(non-ssl client) it is giving exception.
**"Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?"**

Please suggest.

**Edit 1**
Based on the comment I can say there are two possible solution to this problem.

1. Use two different port, one for SSL and another for non-SSL.
2. Use single port, for both the connection. Once the server received the connection it will detect whether client sends a non-SSL or SSL request. And if it is a SSL request it will convert it to SSLSocket.

First point is easy to implement. For the second point there are two parts, 1st detection of connection whether SSL or non-SSL. 2nd part if SSL convert the Socket to SSLSocket. I was able to achieve the 2nd part and able to convert an Socket to SSLSocket successfully. For the 1st part I am struggling that how to identify whether the connection is SSL(how to detect that client send **"SSL Hello client"**)

After search I found out this
[Detecting SSL connection and converting socket to SSLSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637039/detecting-ssl-connection-and-converting-socket-to-sslsocket)
http://pastebin.com/Q8yVLNp7

```
public static boolean isSSLPacket(BufferedInputStream bis) throws Exception {
        bis.mark(10);
        byte[] fingerPrint = new byte[10];
        try {
            bis.read(fingerPrint, 0, fingerPrint.length);
            bis.reset();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new CCSApplicationException(e);
        }

        if(fingerPrint[0] == 0x16 && fingerPrint[1] == 0x03 && fingerPrint[5] == 0x01){
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
```

This piece of code is detecting whether the connection is SSL or non-SSL. But I am not able to understand what is this logic.

```
if(fingerPrint[0] == 0x16 && fingerPrint[1] == 0x03 && fingerPrint[5]
== 0x01)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Is this logic is correct and reliable?

How this logic is detecting the connection is SSL?

Comment: What about listenning both ways on different ports?

Comment: @gusto2 - Same port to listen the connection request from SSLSocket and Non-SSLSocket.

Comment: I know. I am asking why do you want to make it complicated. In theory - you can use a buffered stream and check if client sent the "SSL Hello client" message and reset the stream. I just don't see reason behind it when two ports could be used

Comment: This is possible but far from easy. Not recommended.

Comment: @gusto2 are you suggesting that I should one ServerSocket for non-ssl connection request which will listen to port1 and another SSLServerSocket for ssl connection request which will listen to port2?
Could you please share the code snippet if any for how to use buffered stream to solve this. How to detect that server sends the SSL Hello Client and how to reset the stream to SSL if.

Comment: @EJP Could you please share how to achieve this either what would be the recommended way.

Comment: Yes, I suggest you should use different sockets for different ports (SSL and Non-SSL) as it is for example for www servers (http port 80, https 443, you should use your own port numbers). And for the code - we are not doing you homework now..

Comment: @gusto2: since 8 it's a little easier; you don't have to wrap the stream yourself, you can feed JSSE the already-read input with [`SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(Socket,InputStream,boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html#createSocket-java.net.Socket-java.io.InputStream-boolean-) (But I would still prefer separate ports or an explicit STARTTLS like SMTP.)

Comment: @dave: unless it is homework with artificial constraints I thing the idea of "dual" purpose port is bad.  There is really no reason to do things more complicated than necessary

Comment: @MayankGupta No I can't. It is really too complex to answer here. Review/revise your requirement. Too broad.

Comment: @gusto2 I have edited the question, please have a look and suggest.

Comment: @MayankGupta: - the code posted looks like it may work (I am sure if for all TLS versions). For "How this logic is detecting.." - read the code, do not just copy/paste. We could explain, but we cannot make you understand for you. And the last - is it an artificial homework? If not, than you REALLY should head all good advice here just use separate ports. I consider this as a VERY bad idea. This dual purpose stream just goes against many principles in programming and can bring you more headache debugging, maintaining, supporting and securing your solution.

Comment: @gusto2 - I don't want to understand the logic. Let me rectify my question. I am just asking what would be the difference between SSL and non-SSL request, by which I will be able identify that the landed request is SSL or not. I can write the logic myself, but before that I should know the difference.

Comment: @EJP I have rewrite my question. My only question is there any way to identify that the landed request is SSL or not? What would be the difference between these type of request by which I can detect.

Comment: @MayankGupta: the socket and request is the same, so you have to read ahead the data to see if data match bytes from SSL handshake protocol. That is written in the code logic. "I don't want to understand the logic" - then why we should bother to explain?

Comment: @gusto2 Thank you very much. May be I was bad with words but actually I want to understand the concept.

Comment: @MayankGupta what EXACTLY you don't understand here? The request payload and socket is the same, SSL is only encrypting layer / envelope. So you need to "read ahead" the stream if the bytes correspond with SSL handshake messages (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246) and then push back the already read bytes. You already have a code snippet. It is not reliable, if the plain payload will contain the same bytes as checked SSL message, you are unable to distinguish. Next issue is controlling network access. So we advice you to keep it simple and use two ports.

Comment: @gusto2 - Thanks for explaining in details. So that logic is not reliable(if plain payload will contain same bytes as supposed to be received from SSL). Now will consider this while implementing the same.